# Sort documents by a present field and a calculated value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

How would I go about displaying the best reviews and the worst reviews at the top of the page.

I think the user's "useful" and "notUseful" votes should have an effect on the result.

I have reviews and if people click on the useful and notUseful buttons their Id gets added to the appropriate array (useful or notUseful).

you can tell what a positive or a negative score is by the "overall" score. that is 1 through 5. so 1 would be the worst and 5 would be the best.

I guess If someone gave a review with a 5 overall score but only got one useful but someone gave a score with a 4 overall and 100 people clicking on "useful" the one with 100 people should be shown as the best positive?

I only want to show 2 reviews at the top of the page the best and the worst worst review if there are ties with the overall scores the deciding factor should be the usefulness. so if there are 2 reviews with the same overall score and one of them has 5 usefuls and 10 notUsefuls that would be -5 usefuls and in the other review someone has 5 usefuls and and 4 notUsefuls that would be 1 usefuls so that would be shown to break the tie.

I'm hopping to do it with one mongoose query and not aggregation but I think the answer will be aggregation.

I guess there could be a cut off like scores greater than 3 is a positive review and lower is negative review.

I use mongoose.
Thanks in advance for your help.

some sample data.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5929f89a54aa92274c4e4677"),
    "compId" : ObjectId("58d94c441eb9e52454932db6"),
    "anonId" : ObjectId("5929f88154aa92274c4e4675"),
    "overall" : 3,
    "titleReview" : "53",
    "reviewText" : "53",
    "companyName" : "store1",
    "replies" : [],
    "version" : 2,
    "notUseful" : [ObjectId("58d94c441eb9e52454932db6")],
    "useful" : [],
    "dateCreated" : ISODate("2017-05-27T22:07:22.207Z"),
    "images" : [],
    "__v" : 0
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5929f8dfa1435135fc5e904b"),
    "compId" : ObjectId("58d94c441eb9e52454932db6"),
    "anonId" : ObjectId("5929f8bab0bc8834f41e9cf8"),
    "overall" : 3,
    "titleReview" : "54",
    "reviewText" : "54",
    "companyName" : "store1",
    "replies" : [],
    "version" : 1,
    "notUseful" : [ObjectId("5929f83bf371672714bb8d44"), ObjectId("5929f853f371672714bb8d46")],
    "useful" : [],
    "dateCreated" : ISODate("2017-05-27T22:08:31.516Z"),
    "images" : [],

    "__v" : 0
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5929f956a692e82398aaa2f2"),
    "compId" : ObjectId("58d94c441eb9e52454932db6"),
    "anonId" : ObjectId("5929f93da692e82398aaa2f0"),
    "overall" : 3,
    "titleReview" : "56",
    "reviewText" : "56",
    "companyName" : "store1",
    "replies" : [],
    "version" : 1,
    "notUseful" : [],
    "useful" : [],
    "dateCreated" : ISODate("2017-05-27T22:10:30.608Z"),
    "images" : [],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Comment: It's really not clear what you are asking here. Are you just asking to sort your documents so than where the "overall" value is the same, then another calculation ( a second sort parameter ) has would determine which comes first in the order? Is that then basically `useful - nonUseful = secondSort`? So in these two documents the first document would be first because it has less "noUseful" entries than the other one. Is that a correct interpretation?

Comment: for the most part yes. so I should do a find and sort by overall score in the same query. for the result: the obj at the beginning will be the lowest overall score if I sort ascending. then I need to do my second algorithm from the return of the `.find`. I guess that sound easy. I just have an object and I could get the ones that are the lowest and then get the ones that are the most useful by doing `useful - nonUseful` and which ever one is higher will be the worst review but most the useful.

Comment: I'm going to read your answer but I just wanted to say the part that is harder for me to explain . The tricky part is the stuff I mentioned in the question where if there is an overall scores of 4 and 5 but the one with the overall score of 4 has a lot more useful votes, that's when the review with the 4 will be displayed rather than the 5. Just wanted to say that. Thanks

Comment: As stated, your question really could have been a lot clearer than it is. I think I answered basically covering the options, which are essentially you either use aggregate to calculate a value or values to sort on which are not present in the document, or you put that logic into each update of "votes" in order to keep the value(s) present in the document. The actual algorithm for the "score" is really up to you. I'm covering the methods you use to get there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am reading your question correctly then it appears you want a calculated difference of the `"useful"` and `"nonUseful"` votes to also be taken into account when sorting on the `"overall"` score of the documents.

The better option here is include that calculation in your stored documents, but for totality we will cover both options.

### Aggregation

Without changes to your schema and other logic, then aggregation is indeed required to do that calculation. This is best presented as:

```
Model.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
     "netUseful": {
       "$subtract": [
         { "$size": "$useful" },
         { "$size": "$notUseful" }
       ]
     }
  }},
  { "$sort": { "overall": 1, "netUseful": -1 } }
],function(err, result) {

})
```

So you are basically getting the difference between the two arrays, where more `"useful"` responses have a positive impact boosting the ranking ans more `"notUseful"` will reduce that impact. Depending on the MongoDB version you have available you use either [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) with only the additional field or [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) with all the fields you need to return.

The `$sort` is then performed on the combination of the `"overall"` score in ascending order as per your rules, and the new field of `"netUseful"` in descending order ranking "positive" to "negative".

### Re-Modelling

Foregoing aggregation altogether, you get a faster result from the plain query. But this of course means maintaining that "score" in the document as you add members to the array.

In basic options, you are using the [`$inc`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) update operator along with [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) to change the score.

So for a `"useful"` entry, you would do something like this:

```
Model.update(
  { "_id": docId, "useful": { "$ne": userId } },
  { 
    "$push": { "useful": userId },
    "$inc": { "netUseful": 1 }
  },
  function(err, status) {

  }
)
```

And for a `"notUseful"` you do the opposite by "decrementing" with a negative value to [`$inc`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/):

```
Model.update(
  { "_id": docId, "nonUseful": { "$ne": userId } },
  { 
    "$push": { "nonUseful": userId },
    "$inc": { "netUseful": -1 }
  },
  function(err, status) {

  }
)
```

To cover all cases including where a vote is "changed" from `"useFul"` to `"nonUseful"` then you would expand on the logic and implement the appropriate reverse actions with [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/). But this should give the general idea.

**N.B** The reason we *do not use* the [`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) operation here is because we want to make sure the user id is not present in the array when "incrementing" or "decrementing". Thus instead the [`$ne`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/) operator is used to test the value does not exist. If it does, then we do not attempt to modify the array **or** affect the `"netUseful"` value. The same applies to the reverse case of "removing" the user from those votes.

Since the calculation is always maintained with each update, you simply perform as query with a standard `.sort()`

```
Model.find().sort({ "overall": 1, "netUseful": -1 }).exec(function(err,results) {

})
```

So by moving the "cost" into the maintenance of the "votes", you remove the overhead of running the aggregation later. For my money, where this is a regular operation and the "sort" does not rely on other run-time parameters which force the calculation to be dynamic, then you use the stored result instead.